# Send a downloadable product as a gift to somebody else?

Tags: downloadable, gift-card

Is there a way in Magento itself or some plugin to allow people to send downloadable products as a gift to somebody else? In that case the person who bought the product won't have access to the download, but the receiver of the gift will.

Thank you for your help with this.